# Where are pointers used in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers

I am pretty new to C# environment, I have been coding in C++ for a while now. Where exactly will one use pointers in C#? IS it advisable to use pointers in C#?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/24583/any-real-use-of-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pointers, but only in "unsafe" mode. You will never use them in normal C# coding.

All classes inherit from `Object` and are called "Reference" types. These types are passed by *reference*, which is mainly just a pointer under the hood, and hides any details like addresses from the programmer.

These are your "pointers" but you never delete them because everything in C# is garbage collected, and you access them as if you had the object itself (no -> operator).

Types like `int`, `double`, and `char` are "Value" types and are passed by value (just like in C++). You can also pass these by reference, but you have to use the `ref` keyword in the function signature **and** when calling it.

`struct` is the other special case where it is a "Value" type. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx)

Comment: What about struct? Is it pass by value?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, That is a much better explanation than I gave. Thanks! I have edited my answer to use it.

Comment: @user2495173, structs are value types, edited to include this.

Answer (score 3):

The only place that you can actually use pointers in C# is in unsafe regions of code which is generally frowned upon. The rest of the time, the runtime will manage memory for you.